# How to stop a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So I have this code for my discord bot. It is suppose to check if the input entered by user is correct or not. Based on that run the command again by itself. I did it using recursive function. It works as long as user inputs correct string. But i want it to run only three times.

//Code

```
function recurssiveShit() {
            var arr = [];
            var i;
            let hackString = "";

            //create a unique 4 digits array
            while (arr.length < 4) {
               var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
               if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
            }
            console.log(arr);

            //show the array to be sorted
            message.channel.send("Write it in increasing order.\n" +
               `\`${arr[0]},${arr[1]},${arr[2]},${arr[3]},\``);

            //sort the array in increasing order
            arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

            //store the sorted array as string
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               hackString += arr[i];
            }

            //check is user's input is same as sorted array
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 6000 }).then(collected => {
               let check = collected.first().content;
               if (check === hackString) {
                  message.channel.send("Hack Successful");
                  recurssiveShit();
               }
               else {
                  return message.channel.send("Incorrect");
               }
            }).catch(err => {
               console.log("Time ran out");
            })
            console.log(hackString);
      }

      recurssiveShit();
```

Comment: Please edit your code not to include vulgar language.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a variable outside the function, increment it when needed, and check that it hasn't exceeded its limit before recursively firing another function.

```js
var count = 0;
function recurssiveShit() {
 var arr = [];
 var i;
 let hackString = '';

 //create a unique 4 digits array
 while (arr.length < 4) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
 }
 console.log(arr);

 //show the array to be sorted
 message.channel.send(
  'Write it in increasing order.\n' +
   `\`${arr[0]},${arr[1]},${arr[2]},${arr[3]},\``
 );

 //sort the array in increasing order
 arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

 //store the sorted array as string
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  hackString += arr[i];
 }

 //check is user's input is same as sorted array
 message.channel
  .awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 6000 })
  .then((collected) => {
   let check = collected.first().content;
   if (check === hackString) {
    message.channel.send('Hack Successful');
    if (++count !== 3) { // increment counter, than check if it equals three
     recurssiveShit();
    } else {
     // code...
    }
   } else {
    return message.channel.send('Incorrect');
   }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   console.log('Time ran out');
  });
 console.log(hackString);
}

recurssiveShit();
```

Comment: You could alternatively pass a `maxDepth` to the function as a parameter.